Thunderbird is using two different passwords
I use a desktop computer running windows 10.
On my laptop I run Ubuntu.
Thunderbird is on both of them.
The passwords for one account is different for each computer.
And different from the password I use when I go to the Google website.
Am I right in thinking that the passwords for each instance of Thunderbird can be different, have no relationship with each other, nor to the password I use for Google?
Terry

You already have different passwords, right? You say that in the first paragraph. Do you have some application unlock password, or when you are talking about the Thunderbird password, do you mean the password for the email account you've configured IN Thunderbird? Please edit your question to clarify what passwords you're talking about, what you've tried, etc.

Thunderbird has a built-in password manager, which keeps the passwords for each account. You might have a Gmail account with password A, a Yahoo email account with password B, and a Hotmail account with password C. You don't need to put in each password every time you open Thunderbird, because it does that for you for each account.
However, you don't want unauthorized people to have access to Thunderbird, and all those accounts, or to stored, encrypted, local email messages so Thunderbird's single login, with it's Primary Password (which may be different on each machine), provides access to all those accounts and messages.

You can even export a profile from one machine and put it on another. At first, the Thunderbird Primary Password would be the same on both. You can then open Settings (AKA Preferences) and "Change Primary Password" on one machine. The email accounts are unaffected, only the T'bird login has changed.

Thanks Dr Moishe. Just what I needed. I would have liked to have had all this the day before yesterday.
Terry
